# How to access variable of type 'var' outside of method?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, methods

I'm trying to access the value stored in a method variable `var pitch` but I'm not sure how to access this method variable from another method.

Usually I would declare the variable as a class field like this `private var pitch` but it seems you can't do this with a method var.

Does any know how I could access the variable or variable's value from another method?

This is the method where `pitch` is created and assigned the pitch value:

```
private void Myo_OrientationDataAcquired(object sender, OrientationDataEventArgs e)
        {
            const float PI = (float)System.Math.PI;

            var pitch = (int)((e.Pitch + PI) / (PI * 2.0f) * 10);

        }
```

And then the method where I want to access the value is as follows, but when I try to reference `pitch` it `doesn't exist in the current context`:

```
private void Pose_Triggered(object sender, PoseEventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {

                poseStatusTbx.Text = "{0} arm Myo holding pose {1}" + e.Myo.Arm + e.Myo.Pose;
                //error trying to reference pitch here.
                pitch = pitchDefault;


            }));    
        }
```

Comment: use property to set pitch  value and get pitch  value

Comment: *Usually I would declare the variable as a class field like this private var pitch but it seems you can't do this with a method var.* Then use `private int pitch`, after all you **know** that `pitch` is an `int`. (Btw. `var` is not a type.)

Comment: It is [local variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) - you cant access it outside the method .

Comment: Listen carefully, I will say this only once. _There is no type `var`._ Edit: oh, Dirk already said that.

Comment: If you declare your lambda expression inside Myo_OrientationDataAcquired it will capture pitch. But where else are you going to use it?

Comment: var is an illusion of the compiler.  During compilation, the actual type of the variable is deduced, and var is replaced with this within the IL.  Enjoy.

Comment: @BrianJ just some info on why `var` exists. Primarily you want to use it in conjunction with the `new` keyword in order to avoid hugely verbose code. `var carsDictionary = new Dictionary<string,Car>();` In this case `carsDictionary` is **not** a dynamic type, it is just implicitly declared as a `Dictionary<string,Car>`. I think this is the primary misunderstanding of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you have to use a field (or property) and you can't use `var`:

```
private int pitch = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` just means "let the compiler decide what the type should be" - it is not a "variant" or a type in itself.

Since you are casting to `int`, just add a private `int` field:

```
private int pitch;

private void Myo_OrientationDataAcquired(object sender, OrientationDataEventArgs e)
{
    const float PI = (float)System.Math.PI;

    pitch = (int)((e.Pitch + PI) / (PI * 2.0f) * 10);

}

private void Pose_Triggered(object sender, PoseEventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        poseStatusTbx.Text = "{0} arm Myo holding pose {1}" + e.Myo.Arm + e.Myo.Pose;
        //error trying to reference pitch here.
        pitch = pitchDefault;
    }));    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

var is a NOT a type, it is a keyword which means that type of variable will be infered from the right part of statement

in your case pitch will be of Int32 type

to solve your problem, define a private variable in your class outside of Myo_OrientationDataAcquired

```
int pitch;
private void Myo_OrientationDataAcquired(object sender, OrientationDataEventArgs e)
    {
        float PI = (float)System.Math.PI;

        pitch = (int)((e.Pitch + PI) / (PI * 2.0f) * 10);

    }
```